# Maintaining a Session throughout the day

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to maintaing the Session throughout the day? On or before session expires, how do I enforce session throughout the day without giving any session timeout either in IIS or web.config?

Note: Default Session Timeout in IIS – 20 minutes.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't you just set the session timeout to 24 hours?

Comment: Why can't you set it in the web.config?

Comment: @CyberDude: that means that the session is kept alive at the server for an additional 24 hours after the *last* request, taking resources the entire time.

Comment: The answers below suggest that we need to know whether the users browser will remain open during the 24 hour period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you can do is decouple the session from the process by using a SQL (or other database) session state server that holds the serialized copy of the session data attached to a session id. Then you could use a persistent cookie to pass the session id back and forth. Any session that expires could then be regenerated or reinstated.

Since you're wanting to maintain a session all day (which is innately insecure), we'll assume that most security considerations have already been thrown out. If you're concerned about replay attacks, you could use an HMAC to validate cookie session requests by having the session id, datetime, username (if that's part of your data), maybe IP address in a string followed by a one-way salted hash of this data. This way you rehash the data and compare the hash sent with the request with the generated hash from that data to see if the request is valid.

Comment: +1 for using SQL instead of inProc, this will mitigate most problems with having a lot of sessions open at once (which sounds likely in this scenario)

Answer (score 1):

Forcing the page to be refreshed every 10 minutes or so by javascript. The session timeouts are how long after the **last** requested page, the session becomes invalid. When you refresh the page every 10 minutes or so, the session is extended for 20 minutes on every refresh.

Comment: Or refresh a *part* of the page with ajax-like methods - then the user doesn't notice the postback.

Comment: This would not enable a browser to close and maintain session. It's useful if that is not a requirement, but breaks down if the user navigates away for 20 minutes and returns.

Comment: This doesn't keep the session open for 24 hours - it will do it indefinitely (not the requirement here)

Comment: I believe there is also a setting in IIS with the maximum session lifetime, but I could be wrong. You could of course always implement something like that manually (invalidate the session after 24 hours).

Answer (score 0):

If you refuse to change the setting in the web.config to a longer value, you could try to force the browser to refresh within a short time of the session timeout (eg at 17 minutes). There might be other nifty ways.

If you can find a way to do without the session, it will save you pain later. Either use a caching strategy (memcached) or look at your resource usage.

eg Do you really need to serialise X into the session?

Answer (score 0):

**Use StateServer instead of InProc**

This delegates all session handling to a separate database and removes it from the servers process.  This will mitigate problems with eating up server resources which then allows you to increase the session timeout to 24 hours.

I believe this is the only viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Peiter is on the right track -- making fake requests to keep things alive. You definitely don't want to refresh the page, that leads to unwanted updates and such. You don't even need to refresh part of the page. You just need to send an ajax request every X minutes while a user has a browser open to an IHttpHandler that does have session state enabled. This is very, very effective -- we've got one app which is compltely dependent upon sessions for everything that has a 5 minute session timeout. And a session heartbeat that fires every 4.5 minutes. Its been in production upwards of 3 years and we have not lost a session yet. And yes, session state is stored in process in this case -- the use of sessions is so heavy we don't want to wait for them to go out to SQL and back.

PS: protip -- make sure to make the request and response unique; caching kicks in otherwise in certain browsers rendering this trick ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

put a ajax call into a timer, to a method which does nothing "", that's how even the user is on the page but not doing anything means "totally inactive", would not log out, we have implemented the same logic and resolved our problem, our target was 3 to 4 hours, and we did not want to change the value in web.config or using any other way cause of some reasons.

that ajax call would be in a "timer", set the timer time to "any".